# Coordinates of circumcentre of an isosceles triangle in 3D

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, 3d

I have an isosceles triangle in 3D and I need to find the coordinates of the circumcentre of this triangle. I know the coordinates of the three vertices. One method I thought of is to solve equation of sphere using the three vertices. I have to code it, so I would like to know if there is any easier way to do this.

Comment: If you know how to code 3D vector lengths and cross products, you could use [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Higher_dimensions) for $p_0$. The formula for $r$ there gives the radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: I see you have neither gotten a full answer nor responded to my comment. If you do not know how to code vector operations and would like some help, let us know and I or someone else can give you some helpful (pseudo)code.

Comment: I apologize. I was working on this problem and found a way to do it, so I completely forgot about the question that I posted. I saw the formula that you suggested. I don't know how to code cross products but would like to learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{A} = (A_1, A_2, A_3)$, $\vec{B} = (B_1, B_2, B_3)$, $\vec{C} = (C_1, C_2, C_3)$ be the three vertices of a triangle $ABC$ in any dimension. Let $a, b, c$ be the lengths of corresponding sides, i.e.

$$\begin{cases}
a &= |\vec{B} - \vec{C}| = \sqrt{(B_1-C_1)^2+(B_2-C_2)^2+(B_3-C_3)^2}\\
b &= |\vec{C} - \vec{A}| = \sqrt{(C_1-A_1)^2+(C_2-A_2)^2+(C_3-A_3)^2}\\
c &= |\vec{A} - \vec{B}| = \sqrt{(A_1-B_1)^2+(A_2-B_2)^2+(A_3-B_3)^2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Define three constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ by
$\displaystyle\;
\begin{cases}
\alpha &= a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)\\
\beta  &= b^2(c^2+a^2-b^2)\\
\gamma &= c^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)
\end{cases}
$.

The circumcenter of triangle $ABC$ (in the plane holding the triangle) is located at

$$\frac{\alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + \gamma \vec{C}}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}
= \left(
\frac{\alpha A_1 + \beta B_1 + \gamma C_1}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma},
\frac{\alpha A_2 + \beta B_2 + \gamma C_2}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma},
\frac{\alpha A_3 + \beta B_3 + \gamma C_3}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}
\right)
$$
The $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ above is essentially the [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Barycentric_coordinates)
of the circumcenter with respect to $\triangle ABC$. Since it only depends on
the side lengths, above formula works in any dimension.

Comment: This formula is neat and easy to code. I would like to explain how I did it. First, I found the perpendicular bisector unit vector for the side which is different. I also found the radius of the circumcircle. I multiplied the radius with the unit vector which means I have now the vector from one of the vertices to the circumcentre. I know the vector for the vertex from origin. Using triangle law of vector addition, I found the vector of circumcentre from origin.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you avoid the square roots solving a sphere equation will probably imply. Instead, I'd intersect two perpendicular bisector planes of the triangle edges with the plane of the triangle. That way, everything is linear.

Personally I'd perform the computation using projective geometry, but that may be a matter of taste and education, and explaining it here isn't shorter than doing things the conventional way, using the normal representation of each plane and solving a set of three linear equations to intersect them.

Comment: Can you provide any link where I can find more about projective geometry method that you suggested?

Comment: [Perspectives on Projective Geometry](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/3642172857) does 2D mostly. [Geometriekalküle](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3642025293) is in German. For lines in space you could try [Plücker coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates) and [MSE questions on these](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pl%C3%BCcker+coordinates). The key point is probably that if you have the equations of three planes, then the coordinates of their common point can be computed using the $3\times3$ minors from the plane equations.